# TTThumbsViewController + navigationController issue

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, three20

I am only using Three20 for a gallery in my app.

When I push my `.. : TTThumbsViewController` from another view, the navigation bar is not the color I want it to be (as per the rest of my app). I have set up a `TTDefaultStyleSheet` as per [this stackoverflow QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653767/three20-library-subclass-of-ttphotoviewcontroller-has-an-opaque-navigation-bar/1662188#1662188). Is there something special I have to do as I am only using the TTThumbsViewController?

The thumbs view is also created with extra space at the top, as though it is leaving room for a navigation controller, without knowing that one is already there. How can I tell the `TTThumbsViewController` to use the existing `uinavigationcontroller`? Or behave as though it is?

```
MYThumbsViewController *mYThumbsViewController = [MYThumbsViewController alloc];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mYThumbsViewController animated:YES];
```

The problem depicted graphically:

[alt text http://www.imgplace.com/img594/1309/39testapp.png](http://www.imgplace.com/img594/1309/39testapp.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

In my `ThumbsViewController` I have this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UINavigationController* navController = self.navigationController;

    navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

    [self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
}
```

The thumbs are now in the correct position.

Comment: > I want to change the bar style ,if i gave any other style other than UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent then i get the above problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If you do not want to use a transparent navigation bar, this issue can be corrected by implementing the following method:

```
- (void) updateTableLayout {

self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 0, 0);
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(TTBarsHeight(), 0, 0, 0);}
```

Comment: This solution, not Misa's (sorry Misa), totally worked for me.  Thanks...randomly generated username :)

Comment: Was having the same problem, and I found that I needed both suggestions to get it to work.  Thanks to everyone! :)